# What do highlighted and red rows mean in EasyTag?

Tags: documentation, id3, mp3-tag, easytag

From the terrible documentation, it seems red/bold means "Automatic corrections" are applied: docs says "useless spaces in fields"? I'm not sure which spaces these are but all 240 songs are red(I think this is from general setting "strip ID3 tags if all ID3 tags are empty"), but I can't find what highlighted rows means (it's not every other row, and also hurts my eyes).

[image]

Comment: According to http://src.gnu-darwin.org/ports/audio/easytag/work/easytag-2.1/doc/EasyTAG_Documentation.html this is what it says about the red lines:  "After the various operations over the files, those who were changed and need to be saved are displayed in red in the list of files."

Comment: @Terrance I figured so, as my question was more of how to interrogate the program on what it changed. The highlighted rows still puzzle me.

Comment: For me, it just renders filenames bold. Not sure how you achieve the visual effect you show.

Comment: I am going to venture to say that the reason it looks that way to you is probably from your theme on your system that you are using, plus your preferences in the application itself might have something to do with the way it looks.

Comment: I looked this up again and EasyTAG hasn't had a release since 2016 even for important bugfixes, so I think maintenance stopped.